# How to refresh a div after hiding contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, web

I have the following code:

```js
// I am filling the data of the "MultiSelectDialog_List" div using javascript like this:

var s = ''; // JSON string ----- YOU NEED TO ADD AN EXAMPLE OF S
var jsonData = JSON.parse(s);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {

  // Hold the original list

  $("#MultiSelectDialog_List").append("<input type='checkbox'  id ='" + jsonData[i][idProp] + "'  value='" +
    jsonData[i][idProp] + "' data-value='" + jsonData[i][nameProp].toLowerCase() + "' > <label data-value ='" +
    jsonData[i][nameProp].toLowerCase() + "'  id ='lbl" + jsonData[i][idProp] + "'>" + jsonData[i][nameProp] + "</label> <br/>");
}



// Then I am using this script to hide some content:

var enteredText = $("#MultiSelectDialog_Search").val();
var ary = $("input[type='checkbox']:not([data-value*='" + enteredText.toLowerCase() + "'])");

for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
  $("#" + ary[i]["id"]).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiSelectDialog" title="Select">
  <input type="text" id="MultiSelectDialog_Search" name="MultiSelectDialog_Search" onchange="multiSelectDialog_Search_TextChanged()" />
  <div id="MultiSelectDialog_List" data-value="">
    <!--The data will goes here-->
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="MultiSelectDialog_Values" id="MultiSelectDialog_Values" />
  <button id="MultiSelectDialog_Submit" onclick="multiSelectDialog_SubmitButton_Click()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

The problem is that the content of the div are not redrawen correctly after hiding some elements. Check the image:

[Before hiding elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Es3.png)

[When hiding elements, see the gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Rf2.png)

How should I refresh the div? I tried to use hide() and show(), fadein(). but did not work.

Comment: Can you give a JSON-data example?

Comment: are you expecting the inside elements to line up after you hide them, so that there is no empty space?

Comment: @Martin exactly

Comment: @zeropublix [{"EnName":"Device Linked Officer","ArName":"Device Linked Officer","Status":false,"Project":"CMS","ID":"ROL29","IsOrderNumRequired":true,"IsTimeInterval":false,"IsHealthCare":true,"isBiller":false},{"EnName":"pharmacist","ArName":"pharmacist","Status":false,"Project":"CMS","ID":"ROL30","IsOrderNumRequired":true,"IsTimeInterval":false,"IsHealthCare":true,"isBiller":false},{"EnName":"Store & Pharmacy","ArName":"Store & Pharmacy","Status":false,"Project":"CMS"}]

Comment: You could remove the elements entirely instead of hiding them, see if that redraws the thing correctly. If not, you might have to refresh the element with the removed pieces. I.e. via AJAX.

Comment: @Martin I used .remove(), but same result.Can you explain your idea pls?

Comment: Could you create a working snippet out of your code? It will be easier to fix something where we can actually *see* the problem. --- Ok, I've created much of the snippet for you, can you modify it with correct data to make it work?

Comment: @Plexis Plexis what I basically mean is, have your selection in a completely seperate file, load it in via AJAX through a get request. Then perform whatever you need to perform, parse the logic through another get request (something that you can use to logically apply whatever functionality you wish to the select menu). That will refresh your select menu and hopefully display it correctly.

Comment: @PlexisPlexis hey can you look this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/GameTag/pgL1v368/ I think it's gonna help you, if not told me why

Comment: @GameTag the fiddle works great! what was the problem, can u explain pls?

Comment: @PlexisPlexis the selector of your variable `ary` dosen't work for me. Generally I prefer manipulate `not` and `data` with jQuery's tool that's why I created a jQuery collection to store the original list and manipulate each item when input `keyup` is fired

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // use localStorage.removeItem('show'); to unset an item
    var show = localStorage.getItem('show');
    if(show === 'true'){
        $('#MultiSelectDialog_List').show();
    }
    
    $("#btn").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#MultiSelectDialog_List').show();
        localStorage.setItem('show', 'true');
    });
});
```

Comment: how can I specify which item to set/unset

Answer (score 1):

```js
// I am filling the data of the "MultiSelectDialog_List" div using javascript like this:

var s = '[{"EnName":"Device Linked Officer","ArName":"Device Linked Officer","Status":false,"Project":"CMS","ID":"ROL29","IsOrderNumRequired":true,"IsTimeInterval":false,"IsHealthCare":true,"isBiller":false},{"EnName":"pharmacist","ArName":"pharmacist","Status":false,"Project":"CMS","ID":"ROL30","IsOrderNumRequired":true,"IsTimeInterval":false,"IsHealthCare":true,"isBiller":false},{"EnName":"Store & Pharmacy","ArName":"Store & Pharmacy","Status":false,"Project":"CMS"}]'; // JSON string ----- YOU NEED TO ADD AN EXAMPLE OF S
var jsonData = JSON.parse(s);
var idProp = 'ID';
var nameProp = 'EnName';

for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
  // Hold the original list
  $("#MultiSelectDialog_List").append("<input type='checkbox'  id ='" + jsonData[i][idProp] + "'  value='" +
    jsonData[i][idProp] + "' data-value='" + jsonData[i][nameProp].toLowerCase() + "' > <label data-value ='" +
    jsonData[i][nameProp].toLowerCase() + "'  id ='lbl" + jsonData[i][idProp] + "'>" + jsonData[i][nameProp] + "</label> <br/>");
}



// Then I am using this script to hide some content:

function multiSelectDialog_SubmitButton_Click() {
  var enteredText = $("#MultiSelectDialog_Search").val();
  var ary = $("input[type='checkbox']:not([data-value*='" + enteredText.toLowerCase() + "'])");

  for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    $("#" + ary[i]["id"]).hide();
  }
}

function multiSelectDialog_Search_TextChanged() {
  // TODO
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiSelectDialog" title="Select">
  <input type="text" id="MultiSelectDialog_Search" name="MultiSelectDialog_Search" onchange="multiSelectDialog_Search_TextChanged()" />
  <div id="MultiSelectDialog_List" data-value="">
    <!--The data will goes here-->
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="MultiSelectDialog_Values" id="MultiSelectDialog_Values" />
  <button id="MultiSelectDialog_Submit" onclick="multiSelectDialog_SubmitButton_Click()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

I've updated the given snippet a little bit to try to achieve a working code.

Your problem is, that its not really clear what `idProp` or `nameProp` is (so I decided on my own).

Another problem you will face:

You do hide stuff, but you never get it back. Once a checkbox got hidden its gone for good.

Comment: idprop and nameprop are used to set the value of the checkboxes and their text respectively

Comment: thanks, now in the multiSelectDialog_Search_TextChanged() the items should be hidden, I already submitted the code I use in it

Comment: var enteredText = $("#MultiSelectDialog_Search").val();
    var ary = $("input[type='checkbox']:not([data-value*='" + enteredText.toLowerCase() + "'])");

    for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
      $(  "#"+ary[i]["id"]) .hide();
    }
    var ary = $("label:not([data-value*='" + enteredText.toLowerCase() + "'])");

    for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
        $("#" + ary[i]["id"]).hide();
   
    }